# Find the mean and sd with multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `diary14` which contains two columns `activity` and `day`. The column `activity` contains names like `leisure`, `work`, and `home`. Each of these names represents a 10-minute interval.
The column `day` contains numerical values `1`, `2`, and `3` each corresponds to `weekdays`, `saturday`, and `sunday` respectively.

| **activity** | **day** |
|    work      |    1    |
|    leisure   |    1    |
|   leisure    |    2    |
|     home     |    3    |

To find out how much time is spent each day, I used the nrow() and subset() functions:

```
nrow(subset(diary14, activity == "leisure" & day == 1))
nrow(subset(diary14, activity == "leisure" & day == 2))
nrow(subset(diary14, activity == "leisure" & day == 3))

nrow(subset(diary14, activity == "work" & day == 1))
nrow(subset(diary14, activity == "work" & day == 2))
nrow(subset(diary14, activity == "work" & day == 3))

nrow(subset(diary14, activity == "home" & day == 1))
nrow(subset(diary14, activity == "home" & day == 2))
nrow(subset(diary14, activity == "home" & day == 3))
```

Running these lines gave me a value. All I have to do is manually multiply the values by 10 to get the total minutes.

Is there a way to summarise these values and find the mean and standard deviation?

I used the following function to summarise but couldn't use the `mean()` and `sd()` functions because the names are not numerical values.

```
diary14%>%
group_by(activity)%>%
summarise(n=n())
```

Comment: Please provide some data, e.g. `dput(head(your_data))`. Add it as text. I think you are looking for `aggregate()` with `by = list(activity, day)` but hard to tell without seeing actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(head = TRUE, text= "activity day
      work          1    
      leisure       1    
     leisure        2    
       home         3") 
       
df %>%
  summarise(total_minutes = n() * 10, .by = c(activity, day)) %>% 
  summarise(mean_minutes = mean(total_minutes),
            sd_minutes = sd(total_minutes), .by = activity)
```

```
  activity mean_minutes sd_minutes
1     work           10         NA
2  leisure           10          0
3     home           10         NA
```